# Correct syntax for adding two $_POST variables in PHP

Tags: php, post, syntax, addition

I'm trying to add two $_POST variables, like so:

```
$points = $_POST['old_points'] + $_POST['new_points'];
```

*(Line 48)*

Which works fine, except it produces the following error:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 48

I can't figure out what the problem is here.

Comment: What is the values of `$_POST['old_points']` and `$_POST['new_points']`?

Comment: what is the type of those variable?

Comment: show us the value of both variables

Comment: @yasaryousuf A string. Everything in `$_POST` is a string (assuming you didn't manipulate it…).

Comment: use dot `.` to add strings

Comment: @Alfie It means those values are *not a number*; maybe they're "abcdef" or something completely different.

Comment: Maybe they are not exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you need  convert the content of $post as a correct number

```
  $points = floatval($_POST['old_points']) + floatval($_POST['new_points']);
```